# references for table alternative

Tags: tables, ux-designer

Do you have any references you can link me to, where I could **display this data, but not in a table**?

This will be used by 500 to 10000 people, and they want to have :

- drag and drop for re-ordering,
- maybe some filtering,
- something slick,
- maybe Angular JS powered..

[image: current table]

Comment: What's the problem with using a table? The current UI you included looks slick, and with all the features you've mentioned, it's hard to beat a table.

Comment: You really need to give us more info, because on the face of it it's not clear why it can't be a table? From a UX perspective, especially since you want users to be able to drag and drop for re-ordering, it's hard to go past a table or list. Also, can you clarify why your users may want something that is Angular JS powered? Or is that actually your preference? I can't imagine most users would even know what's going on in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I have no idea how you get that data, and this means A LOT. It's not the same to display data from a search or pre-filter than to display all data by default (specially if we're talking of anything above 100 results)

Personally, I think what you have now is probably the best option. However, you may want to take a look to more [table UI examples.](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/ultimate-guide-to-table-ui-patterns) or something like [Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/Patterns/Alternative%20Views.aspx)

If you're still looking for alternatives to tables, the only realistic option I can think of is [cards](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html), but keep in mind that, while they fit in your request, they're not very useful if you have a lot of results to show. However, if you have a pre-filtering process (search, faceted search, filtering) this could be very helpful and visually more interesting than a table.

Then again, based on the extremely restricted info you offered, I think you need to use a table

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably figure out the most common use cases and design from there.  If most of the users are looking for a particular category of this data, then you could create charts and graphs based on them and allow the user to drill down by clicking on them.  For example, if users care about the Source and Reference data, you can create categories of these. Or create categories of the User types.

If they are looking for a list just to find a particular user, well, that's what you've got.   You could go the kayak.com route and overlay filters if that's helpful to them or at least add a search box.